# Extracting values from xml using xpath based on a condition

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am using xpath to parse and get the attribute values from a xml file.

This is my xpath expression

```
./result/object/group[@mode = 'invalid']
```

The xpath generates

```
<group mode="invalid" name="3"/>
<group mode="invalid" name="4"/>
```

I would want to further, parse and get the details of the name, either like

```
name="3"
name="4"
```

or just

```
"3"
"4"
```

I am not sure of how to proceed further based on conditions.

Comment: I used this ./result/object/group[@mode = 'invalid']/@name and i got the ouput of name = 3 and name = 4

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "name" by using the `GetAttribute` method.
For example in your case:

```
string name  = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("./result/object/group[@mode = 'invalid']")).GetAttribute("name");
```

Comment: Can we do this example in C#? We do not have a corresponding XML class for extracting in c#

Comment: Yes, you did not attach the language so i posted the code in java. Edited my code now. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finish the operation using ./result/object/group[@mode = 'invalid']/@name to get the name values. I used the following to get the values of the name

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("./result/object/group[@mode = \'invalid\']/@name");

    foreach (XmlAttribute node in xmlNodeList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
    }
```